# AudioRecord on android is not working on marshmallow. Error says uninitialized AudioRecord

Tags: android, audiorecord

I have tried other solutions present in stackoverflow but none worked for me. I have all the permissions specified. This app works on other devices except those having Marshmallow.

**Here is log**

```
03-14 13:17:53.742 5427-5427/com.radiobox.vigilantevoice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.radiobox.vigilantevoice, PID: 5427
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
                                                                           at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:885)
                                                                           at com.radiobox.vigilantevoice.VoiceActivity.plays(VoiceActivity.java:130)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Android permission system has been changed for Marshmallow. So I added the permission in accordance to the new format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android introduced runtime permission which required additional code to be written for permissions. The users are asked for the permissions when they run the app. There are some open source libraries for implementing runtime permission easily. I personally found [this](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) one helpful.